# Normalization of the Bessel function

Tags: special-functions

I would greatly appreciate assistance with the following problem.
show:

$$\int _0 ^\infty J_n(x)dx = 1; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+$$

for $J_o,$ use $$\mathscr{L}{J_o(at)} = \int _0 ^\infty e^{-pt}J_o(at)dt = (p^2 + a^2)^{- \frac{1}{2}}$$

By setting a = 1; p = 0; I obtain that which I was trying to prove. How would I generalize this to other orders of the Bessel function? I tried writing a generalized bessel function in closed form but this proved fruitless.

If I take the Laplace transform  of a bessel function, then the only way to do that would be to do it term by term?

EDIT : I'm still not sure how one would actually take the Laplace Transform of such a function?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you mean by "term by term."  Do you mean as a power series?

Comment: BTW you can find the LT of Bessels here: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/laplace8.pdf

Comment: Yes I did mean as a series. Thank you for that link, it is perfect

Comment: I realize that that question mark was unnecessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*: 
Using the [integral representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals) of the Bessel function 
$$J_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi dt\, e^{-i(n t - x \sin t)}$$
we find 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty dx\, e^{-p x} J_n(x) 
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi dt\, \frac{e^{-i n t}}{p-i\sin t}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This integral can be handled using the [methods of residue calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration). 
Let $z=e^{-i t}$ so the contour is the unit circle. 
Only one of the poles lies inside the contour.

*Addendum*: The integral in terms of $z$ is 
$$\frac{1}{\pi i} \int_\Gamma dz\, \frac{z^n}{z^2+2p z-1},$$
where $\Gamma$ is the unit circle traversed in the counterclockwise sense. 
The poles are 
$$z_\pm = -p \pm \sqrt{1+p^2}.$$
Only $z_+$ lies inside the unit circle, so we pick up the residue at $z=z_+$.

Comment: So the pole is at $t = arcsin( \frac {p}{i})$ ? which of course must be less than one in magnitude

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I got it now

Comment: @CactusBAMF: Glad to help. It may be too late, but I've added something above about your previous question.

Comment: Why can we set p=0? For the derivation we assumed o to be positive, didnt we.