# Showing that $\int_0^{\infty} J_n(bx) dx = 1/b$

Tags: integration, induction, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm trying to prove that

$$ \int_0^{\infty}J_n(bx)dx=\dfrac{1}{b}$$

when $b > 0$ and $n$ is a nonnegative integer. From the recurrence relations I arrived at the identity

$$\int_0^{\infty}J_{n+1}(bx)dx=\int_0^{\infty}J_{n-1}(bx)dx,$$

but I do not see how to use this.

Answer (score 4):

As proved [in this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/273115/9754), the $J$-Bessel function is normalized so that
$$ \int_0^\infty J_n(x) dx = 1 $$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$.
This implies your claim after a short substitution.